# How to make files no longer ignored by svn and can be checked in?

Tags: svn

I imported a project into a Subversion repository with import command and found many .a files were ignored automatically. I want to import them again but have not found a easy way.

The svn version is 1.14.1 (r1886195) and OS is Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

`*.a` might be defined as a global ignore pattern; where the file location might vary:
https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#repos-dictated-config

Most likely that's `svn:global-ignores`.

Comment: Ignoring *.a file is a default behavior. I have not set any svn:ignore and svn:global-ignores property ignores.

Comment: @XiongMar there is no default ignore pattern in Subversion. Ignore pattern is configured either on the client side or via the properties in your repository.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to remove the entire project from repository and import it again with the [`--no-ignore`](https://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.ref.svn.html#svn.ref.svn.sw.no_ignore) option.